# How to validate form using if statement javascript in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I need to validate login function. I added my Login.html file and LoginController.js file. I want to validate this from using this javascript. This is angularjs code. after that I have to set php url for this code.

**Login.html**

```js
$scope.submitForm = function() {

    var user_email = user_email;
    var user_password = user_password;

    if(user_email && user_password){

     console.log(user_email);
        
    }

    

   };
```

```html
<div ng-controller="LoginController">
        <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">

        <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Username</span>
            <input type="text" name="user_email" ng-model="user.user_email" required>
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Password</span>
            <input type="password" name="user_password" ng-model="user.user_password" required>
          </label>
        </div>

        <span ng-show="userForm.user_email.$touched && userForm.user_email.$invalid">The Username is required.</span> </br>
        <span ng-show="userForm.user_password.$touched && userForm.user_password.$invalid">The Password is required.</span>

        <button class="button button-block button-positive activated">Sign In</button>
        <button onclick="location.href='#/login/:friendId/register/';"  class="button button-block button-positive activated">Register</button>
        
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: I guess you haven't made any research before ?

Comment: I don't have any idea pls can u give me answer

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

Comment: `var x = x;` - guarantees x is assigned `undefined`

Comment: I know how to validate frontend, But I need to validate using javascript

Comment: `var x = x;` what is this

Comment: @DRK this `var user_email = user_email;`

Comment: `var user_email = user_email;` Is this wrong

Answer (score 0):

Made changes in your provided code,on click of Register/ Sign In you can call `submitForm()` function through `ng-click` to evaluate the form values.Check the below code snippet for working model.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ng'])

.controller('LoginController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.submitForm = function() {

      var user_email = $scope.user.user_email;
      var user_password = $scope.user.user_password;

      if (user_email && user_password) {

        console.log(user_email);

      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="LoginController">
  <form name="userForm">

    <div class="list">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Username</span>
        <input type="text" name="user_email" ng-model="user.user_email" required>{{user.user_email}}
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Password</span>
        <input type="password" name="user_password" ng-model="user.user_password" required>{{user.user_password}}
      </label>
    </div>

    <span ng-show="userForm.user_email.$touched && userForm.user_email.$invalid">The Username is required.</span> 
    </br>
    <span ng-show="userForm.user_password.$touched && userForm.user_password.$invalid">The Password is required.</span>

    <button class="button button-block button-positive activated">Sign In</button>
    <button ng-click="submitForm()" class="button button-block button-positive activated">Register</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have your tried the snippet I have provided it s working here !